# How to get HtmlResponse type in custom CacheStorage in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

i am writing a custom cache backend in scrapy and I want to save the body into elasticsearch for full-text search. The default response type i am getting is `scrapy.http.response.Response` which contains bytes and when i try to encode to string, it goes to something like this `\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003�}�r۸��o�j�\u0001f���\u0019�C�-۲��|N2;�q�Φ���\u000b\"!�6Er\bҲN���\u001a�o�e\u001fe�d�\u001b EJ�,[ά�Ιql\u0012\u0004\u001a�F���h` .

So the question is; how can I can get HtmlResponse type response in the store_response, so that I can get the actual text ! I looked into settings, count find any.

```
class ESCacheStorage(object):

    ....
    ....

    def store_response(self, spider, request, response):
        print("response type is {}".format(type(response)))
        # response type is <class 'scrapy.http.response.Response'>
        # But i want response type <class 'scrapy.http.response.HtmlResponse'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COMPRESSION_ENABLED': False` in the `settings.py` fixed this issue.